# Java- add an editable row to a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception, defaulttablemodel

I have a Java GUI that displays a JTable and a button. When the button is clicked, I want to add a new editable row of cells to the table. I am trying to do this using the following `ActionListener()`, which I have assigned to the button:

```
addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("'Add' button pressed. ");
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jEntityFilterTable.getModel();
        model.addRow(new Object[]{"Site", "Application", "Entity"});
        System.out.println("--- ActionListener added to 'addBtn' ---");
    }
});
```

In the console, when I click the button, I see the message stating "'Add' button pressed. "... However, I then get an exception which says:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

I assume that this is occurring on the `model.addRow...` line, since that is the only place I've used an array, but I'm not sure why I'm getting that error- I'm creating an empty Object array, and not defining its size, so surely it shouldn't have a problem with the index no matter how many elements I add to it- it's an array with a dynamic size.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong here?

**Edit 27/06/2014 @ 09:50**

I've tried changing the method slightly, so I now have the following code:

```
addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("'Add' button pressed. ");
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jEntityFilterTable.getModel();

        Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();
        row.add("Site");
        row.add("Application");
        row.add("Entity");

        System.out.println("Row Count: " + model.getRowCount());
        System.out.println("1st Column: " + model.getColumnName(0));
        System.out.println("Column Count: " + model.getColumnCount());

        model.addRow(row);

        System.out.println("--- ActionListener added to 'addBtn' ---");
    }
});
```

When I run my application, and click the button to which I've added the `ActionListener()`, I see the following output in my console:

> 'Add' button pressed.
>
> Row Count: 0
>
> 1st Column: SITE
>
> Column Count: 3
>
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

It would appear that this exception is occurring on the line:

```
model.addRow(row);
```

I can't work out why I'm getting the exception on this line- it looks correct to me... Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you insreting 3 values in a row or more than that ?

Comment: How many columns does your `Model` have?  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Comment: Render the relevant code to solve the problem,this much is insufficient to get the complete details!

Comment: I'm only inserting 3 values into the row- `model` has 3 columns...

Comment: Ok, so I think I may be getting the error because the `Object[]` that I'm creating there is empty...  am I not passing 'Site', 'Application' & 'Entity' into that array? Or should I not be passing anything at all into the parenthesis of `model.addRow()`?

Comment: Question edited to show updated code and error output.

Comment: `model has 3 columns...` you may want the model to have 3 columns, but did you actually create the TableModel with 3 columns. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.